# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound doesn't play over bluetooth on iOS 8 but works on iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, audio, bluetooth, ios8

Can anyone help me update the following code that works fine on iOS 7.0 (iPhone 4s) when connected to car bluetooth but not on iOS 8.1.3 (iPhone 5)?

Music plays from iPhone over car audio with both devices but CAF file sound only interrupts music with iOS 7. iOS 8 app sounds are not heard at all. With both iOS devices, identical code, identical CAF file, identical car (2013 Mazda CX5).

Both iOS devices play music and app sounds identically through iPhone speaker when not connected to car via bluetooth.

```
- (void) playSoundFileNowNamed: (NSString*) fileName {
if (!isAudioAlreadyPlaying) {
    isAudioAlreadyPlaying = YES;
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],&soundID);
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, NULL, NULL,
        PlaySystemSoundCompletedCallback, (__bridge_retained void *) self);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
}
```

}

Any help greatly appreciated

Robert

Comment: I am currently experiencing this issue as well, have you had any luck?

Comment: @Simon. Were you able to get this solved?